# Parametrization of $3 \times 3$ unitaries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, parametrization, unitary-matrices

Consider a $2 \times 2$ unitary operator $U$.

There is a way to parametrize $U$, as

$$
U = e^{i \alpha} R_z(\phi) R_x(\theta) R_z(\lambda),
$$

where $R_x, R_y$, and $R_z$ are $2 \times 2$ rotation matrices, given by

\begin{equation}
R_t(\theta) = e^{-i \theta \sigma_t/2},
\end{equation}

where $\sigma_x, \sigma_y,$ and $\sigma_z$ are [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices).

Is there a similar way to parametrize a $3 \times 3$ unitary operator $U$?

Comment: I would search the Gell-Mann matrices (equivalent to the Pauli matrices). Also, here is a parameterization for individual matrix elements: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/237988/good-reference-on-the-parametrization-of-su3-and-sun

Comment: I looked into Gell-Mann matrices, but it was not clear how to  decompose a general SU(3) matrix with the Gell Mann matrices. Do I just multiply out the corresponding rotation matrices of each Gell Mann matrix? For the $2 \times 2$ unitary case, the matrix $R_z$ is repeated twice (see my question above) when we are decomposing a general unitary matrix. Is any matrix repeated for the $3 \times 3$ case?

Comment: There are common parameterizations using rotations and phases used in neutrino physics, see e.g. Eq.(1) in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1249. Is that similar enough, or were you looking for a more specific factorization?

Comment: Is the equation 1 there a unitary matrix and is it a general element of SU(3)? It wasn't clear from the text around it.

Comment: It‘s unitary, but only SU(3) for certain values of $\eta$. And I believe it is fully general, but I don’t have a reference to hand.